# Keyframe animation flickering on scaling Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, scaling

Hi i have created a game which runs on different devices on different resolutions. so to adjust the resolution i am using dynamic css scaling , so due to scaling my keyframe animation is flickering massively on firefox. The sprite animation is used within a div background-imgae. Please help me to get rid out of this.
Below is the source code and url of animation:

Please open it in firefox.

https://trcdev.oupchina.com.hk/test/kg_game3/#/home

```
.boboFeather {
background-image: url(‘../../assets/images/home/boboFeather.png’);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 460px;
height: 489px;
position: absolute;
right: 250px;
bottom: 30px;
animation: BoboFeatherAnim 2s steps(14) infinite;
-webkit-animation: BoboFeatherAnim 2s steps(14) infinite;
-moz-animation: BoboFeatherAnim 2s steps(14) infinite;
-ms-animation: BoboFeatherAnim 2s steps(14) infinite;
-o-animation: BoboFeatherAnim 2s steps(14) infinite;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes BoboFeatherAnim {
from {
background-position: 0px;
}
to {
background-position: -6440px;
}
}

@-moz-keyframes BoboFeatherAnim {
from {
background-position: 0px;
}
to {
background-position: -6440px;
}
}

@-ms-keyframes BoboFeatherAnim {
from {
background-position: 0px;
}
to {
background-position: -6440px;
}
}

@-o-keyframes BoboFeatherAnim {
from {
background-position: 0px;
}
to {
background-position: -6440px;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes BoboFeatherAnim {
from {
background-position: 0px;
}
to {
background-position: -6440px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` or `-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;`style to the container of a flickering element. To `class="container"` in your case, that contains `.boboFeather` element.

Comment: thanks for the help it works. why it was not working on .boboFeather container. Please explain me if you can. Thanks

Comment: @RaghvendraSingh it is applied on a container and sets up behaviour for child element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style